# NodeJS MongoDB UNIX socket connection

Tags: node.js, mongodb, unix-socket

In a *nodeJS* app, I'd want to connect to my *MongoDB* database via its **UNIX socket** `/tmp/mongdb-27017.sock`. I use the package https://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/?jmp=docs (version 3.1.6), this way:

```
const client = await MongoClient.connect("mongodb://%2Ftmp%2Fmongodb-27017.sock")
```

The URI is referenced in the doc here: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/connection-string/#unix-domain-socket. But in my case it fails with the error:

> MongoNetworkError: failed to connect to server [/tmp/mongodb-27017.sock:27017] on first connect [MongoNetworkError: connect ECONNREFUSED /tmp/mongodb-27017.sock]

Do anyone know if it's possible to connect to a *mongoDB UNIX socket* from *nodeJS*, and if there's something specific to do? Couldn't find specific info in the doc.

Answer (score 3):

For me the solution was *not* to escape the path, contrary to the documentation on [docs.mongodb.com](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/connection-string/#unix-domain-socket). So try

> mongodb:///tmp/mongodb-27017.sock

instead of

> mongodb://%2Ftmp%2Fmongodb-27017.sock

And of course make sure the socket file exists:

> $ ls -al /tmp/mongodb-27017.sock
>   srwxrwxrwx 1 mongodb mongodb 0 Apr  1 21:47 /tmp/mongodb-27017.sock

A more complete example using a user account from another database then the one we're connecting to:

> mongodb://foo:pass@/tmp/mongodb-27017.sock/somedb?authSource=admin

Here a connection is made to the *somedb* database, by user *foo* which is a user account stored in the *admin* database.

Comment: I had also tried this. It returns the same error. My issue is likely to be related to the fact that in my case this socket is a Docker mounted volume (even if I usually don't have troubles with sockets mounted this way). It doesn't matter anymore, I have another way to connect. Thanks for trying!

Answer (score 0):

It is possible by using the full Unix domain socket paths instead of hostname on which mongod should listen for client connections. It started in Mongo 3.6

Comment: I know. My question is about connecting by using Unix sockets **from nodeJS**.